# Django ошибка 500 при отправке письма с сайта через Gmail

Tags: django, email

Все настройки сделаны верно, как рекомендует сам Gmail (С двухэтапной авторизацией и паролями для приложений). С localhost письма отправляются отлично, даже когда ставишь DEBUG = False. Но на залитом на сервак проекте выскакивает 500 ошибка. До "изменений конца Мая 2022" всё работало.
Логи Gunicorn и Nginx ничего Мне не показали.

Comment: В конце мая gmail сменил параметры секюрности. нужно включить 2фа и сгенерить пароль для приложения. его и использовать

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл ответ на этот вопрос Сам.
Проблема заключалась в распознании домена, а именно ссылки на него. `SITE_ID = 1` в `settings.py`, означает, что в таблице django_site id этой записи будет равен 1.
Беда получится, если вы удалите запись с `id=1` через админскую панель на своём же проекте. Поскольку id там SERIALKEY, то следующий будет 2, и так далее. Вы можете сразу и не разобраться, какой id теперь у вашего доменного имени в таблице и чему должен быть равен SITE_ID. Мой id в базе на сервере был уже = 3, а в настройках стоял по прежнему `SITE_ID = 1`. Ведь таблицы на localhost и серваке разные, и подвергались разным манипуляциям. Короче, оставил SITE_ID = 1, а через БД-клиента поменял значение id на 1. Так не совсем правильно делать, ну да ладно.
Всё заработало.
Доменное имя можно проверить `print(get_current_site(request))`